# Unable to access jsonp data returned from WCF to jquery properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, jsonp

I could use another set of eyes - perhaps I  am missing somehting obvious. I wrote a WCF service to return some basic data from my sql server database. It seems to function just fine. Now I am simply trying to dump that data to my webpage like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:35798/restserviceimpl.svc/json/999?callback=?',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); 
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('#gallery').append('<p>' + i + '.'+ item + '</p>');
        });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Using fiddler, it looks to me like correctly format json data is being returned to my webpage (and the alert shows me what looks json data which validates on jsonlint.com), but when I try to iterate over it I simply get one character for each 'each', instead of 'records'. I get 800+ iterations, each containing just one character of the JSON string, instead of the approximate 17 'records' of json data, each with two fields.

So am I getting a string back from my WCF that just 'looks like' JSON, or is my jquery script above have a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, took me almost 2 days of trial an error, not sure if I had the problem on the WCF end or the jQuery end, but this is what I ended up with and works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:35798/restserviceimpl.svc/json/999',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(obj, function (i, item) { $('#gallery').append('<p>' + item.Id + '.' + item.Name + '</p>'); });
        }
    });
});
```

for some reason, which I don't fully understand, I had to add the $.parseJSON(data) line in order to convert the 'JSONP' string that was coming down from my WCF service, into useable JSON in order to be able to iterate over it. It is odd, because I consume JSONP from other places in this app, and didn't have to do this, so it is possible my WCF is sending slightly malformed results, that I need to compensate for in my jQuery, but until I figure out if that is true I am just going to go with what works.

Answer (score 1):

1. What is the value of the Content-Type header? It should be "application/json"
2. What is the data value returned by service? It may be something like "[a,b]" instead of [a,b] - i.e. the whole string maybe in quotes or something like that.

Generally the script looks good.

Comment: I'd agree with Evgeny's point 2.  Typically in jQuery your alert(data) should display [object Object] not a JSON string.

Comment: The content-type header is 'application/x-javqascript', which I *think* is correct for jsonp.

Comment: 'application/x-javqascript' or application/x-javascript' ? Anyway, alert should show [Object object] not a string. I would suggest to play with the content type (application/javascript or application/json - doesn't matter, both work).